# Weather Radar data Overlay in ios route-me framework

Tags: ios, ipad, mapkit, core-location

I am quite new to ios development and i am trying to work with the mapkit and corelocation framework. what i want to do is display recent weather data on a map that shows rainfall, storm etc. I am trying to make something like in the image below.

Link: http://cdn-static.zdnet.com/i/story/70/00/002370/radarscope-mac-os-ogrady.jpg

In order to get the weather data, i would for now use a free tool that could generate a kml file for me(Please advice if any other approach is better). And then would use that kml file to overlay it on the map.

Since this is a test application, the data need not update itself automatically(Would greatly appreciate some pointers on how to approach this as well).

Would the above approach the best solution for accomplishing this or is there another better way? Also, is it possible to get the exact same color coding and the over all look and feel of the map shown in the above image?

I plan on building an ipad app using the ios route-me framework, IOS 5.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Weather Underground's API:

[Weather Underground](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/)

Comment: Thanks for the link to their website. I will dig into their api and see how i could go about using it. Would adding a simple Webview and pointing it to the URL with the parameters work? i ask as i am not very sure if thats the way to use their service from an IOS device. Thank you once again.

Comment: A UIWebView would probably work if you don't want control over the user interface. I'm not 100% sure you are allowed to do that legally, but it's probably ok. You can use a URL like <http://i.wund.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?brand=iphone&query=48103>. The API is used when you want to retrieve raw weather data.

Comment: Hey Eric, Thanks for the link again..i dont think there should be any problem legally but i will go through their terms again to confirm. In order to have control over the view, i plan to have a simple button that links to an action which can pass a request to the url mentioned in your comment. In the URL, i would pass the lat-long details for the center of the map to the URL. That function could make a request and return the data and then display it on a map. i would like to use this as moving within the map becomes possible with this approach..

Comment: Once again, thank you for your support. It has helped me a lot. Appreciate it.